# Pushing image to Azure Container Registry preconfigured with certain config file

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I'd like to use the eclipse-mosquitto image on docker.io in the Azure Container Registry however, it needs to use a config file that you must point to when running the docker container. Is there any way to get the config into Azure when running the image in Container Instances or maybe baking the file into the image? Unsure of what the best option here is.

I have tried just pushing the image and running it in container instances, which works, however since the config is only set to default the port is not correctly open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount Azure File volume to the container and update the config file hosted in that file mount.

More information on how to use File Mount -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files